# RotatingFileHandler is not creating file on crossing maxBytes value

Tags: python, fastapi, python-logging

I am working on rotating file handler. I need another file to be created once the file size crosses the given maxBytes value. but the code does not seems to working fine

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
    
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        RotatingFileHandler("./app.log", maxBytes=100, backupCount=5)
    ],
)

logger = logging.getLogger("DemoLogger")
    
@router.get('/demo_api/v1')
    def default_rd(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
        try:
            Category_data = db.query(models.table_new.id, models.table_new.Label).filter(models.table_new.classCode=='Category').all()
        except Exception:
            logger.exception("Database Error")
            
        else:
            logger.warning("Fetched Category data")
```

Comment: Are you sure you can write to `/app.log` (in the filesystem root)?

Comment: yes i need to write to that file initially...and if this file reaches the size greater than maxBytes file, I need to create another file

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: That is not what I asked. _Can you write to the file at all_, or do you really mean `./app.log`?

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example based on yours happily creates app.log, app.log.1, app.log.2, app.log.3, app.log.4, app.log.5 in the directory the program is run from. Note that `/app.log` was changed to `./app.log`.

If applying changes like these doesn't help, there must be something wrong with other code in your app you aren't showing.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        RotatingFileHandler("./app.log", maxBytes=100, backupCount=5)
    ],
)

logger = logging.getLogger("DemoLogger")

for x in range(1000):
    logger.info("Blah, %s", x)
```

Comment: I have tried this....the file app.log has reached 32KB after running the code. but the files like app.log.1, app.log.2 is not created

Comment: i have checked other part of the code...there is no issues....

Comment: If you run _exactly_ this code, you don't get 5 different `app.log` files? Like, if you copy-paste this to a Python file on your desktop and run it?

Comment: Ya i copy pasted exactly your code...to check whether multiple files getting generated or not...but it didnt create multiple files....what should be done to get it work ?

Comment: i copy pasted the same code...its working but why its not working in my code pasted above

Comment: As I said, there's something else in your code that's wrong that you're not showing. Your code is not a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: I have pasted all the related code....I am fetching the value from the db. I am logging that to the logger file. I am executing the api again and again so that the log file maxByte gets full and it creates app.log.1 file...thats my actual requirement

Comment: Your original code doesn't set the logger level at all. Perhaps that's your problem.

Comment: can i set it in this code ? How to set it and make it work

Comment: Look at the differences between my `basicConfig` call and yours. See the missing `level=` parameter in yours?

Comment: i have set the level in my code but its still not working

Comment: I have modified the code above you can check it

Comment: Again, your code is not a full example so it's hard to fully "check it". Are you absolutely, positively sure that no logging happens when you access that `'/demo_api/v1'` endpoint? Are you sure you're looking in the right directory?

Comment: The logging is happening...but the log file once it reaches the size which we set in maxBytes = 100...its not creating the next file which is app.log.1 etc.,

Comment: Then it may depend on how you're running the application (e.g. under a reloader, or something which spawns more than one process).

Comment: I am reloading the api again and again using swagger...but at some point it should create another file right ? but that's the one which is not happening